# simplexml_load_string return empty result

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

It may be simple, but I am kind of stuck. I want to convert an XML string into PHP object. My XML string is:

```
$a = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <soap:Body>
                <VerifyTxnResponse xmlns="http://www.exmlplekhe.com/">
                    <VerifyTxnResult>BID &lt;11467&gt;</VerifyTxnResult>
                </VerifyTxnResponse>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>';
```

I have tried `var_dump(simplexml_load_string($a));`, but it returns empty `SimpleXMLElement` object. I want to get `VerifyTxnResult` node. I think, `&lt;11467&gt;` is causing the problem. What may be the possible solution?

Thanks.

Comment: The function returns a `SimpleXMLElement` object. What do you mean by "empty result"? And what are you trying to do?

Comment: What exactly it returns?

Comment: @ruslan It returns empty SimpleXMLElement object

Comment: I am trying to get the `VerifyTxnResult` node.

Comment: Try print result with var_dump($a);

Comment: @BrijeshKhatri No, in fact *don't* try that, or you will be tricked into thinking the object is empty, as the OP did. The reason being that SimpleXML has lots of internal data not exposed to PHP's normal debugging functions, so the result of `var_dump` is not consistent with what you can actually access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get `VerifyTxnResult` node

The `simplexml_load_string` function returns an instance of `SimpleXMLElement` which is actually not empty for the XML you posted.

Register the namespace and fetch the node with `xpath` method:

```
$se = simplexml_load_string($a);

$se->registerXPathNamespace('r', 'http://www.nibl.com.np/');

foreach ($se->xpath('//r:VerifyTxnResult') as $result) {
  var_dump((string)$result);
}
```

*Sample Output*

```
string(11) "BID <11467>"
```